# UIGestureRecognizer interrupt UITouch methods

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have a table with custom cells, which has subclass UITableViewCells and for touches animation I use UITouch (code based on this tutorial http://gregprice.co.uk/blog/?p=280) Index of cell under touch I get with using didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I think that is good idea use UISwipeGestureRecognizer to define swipe direction, but UIGestureRecognizer interrupt animation of cell sliding. It's doing because UIGestureRecognizer methods activated before than touchesEnded (UITouch) method finished.

Is it possible to call UISwipeGestureRecognizer after touchesEnded, or after touch release?